# Getting error with datetime function why?

Tags: python, date, datetime

What am trying to do here return the year of the age that I input but I keep on getting an error but why?

```
import datetime

def age():
    x = int(input("enter age here:"))
    tday = datetime.datetime.year()
    print(tday)
    #y = date.year()
    #z = date.today()
    #print(y)

age()
```

**Here is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D8152A85-DCBC-4764-AEF6-B7463F4B3111/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/datetime_fuction.py", line 17, in <module>
     age()
   File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D8152A85-DCBC-4764-AEF6-B7463F4B3111/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/datetime_fuction.py", line 9, in age
     tday = datetime.datetime.year() 
TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is it that you expect `tday = datetime.datetime.year()` to do?  Why do you have the user enter a value for `x` if you never use it?

Comment: I thought by doing that it would let me put the integer of the age?

Comment: Yes, so `x` is the integer representation of what age was entered. But you don't do anything with `x` - the datetime code doesn't use `x` at all...  Can you explain "year of the age that I input" a little more? Do you want the year of birth of someone with the age they input?

Comment: I see I will tweak the code a bit more to see if I get my results that am looking for.

Comment: if you want year of birth then maybe `datetime.datetime.today().year - age` ?

Comment: So am actually close but haven’t got the exact program am looking for ? @furas

Comment: Maybe create new question and better describe what you want to do. And maybe add example data and expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.year` is not callable. Instead, you should try something like `datetime.datetime.now()` to get a datetime object. Then `tday.year` would give you the year attribute of that datetime object.